# Re-visit a file whose buffer I just killed

Tags: buffers, files, ido

I've not found any straightforward way to re-visit a file whose buffer I just killed. Sort of like undoing the killing of the buffer.

I thought about getting the file's path from Ido's virtual buffers list: if you use `recentf` and set `ido-use-virtual-buffers` to `t`, after invoking `ido-switch-buffers` Ido shows the buffer names of recently closed file buffers (not Help buffers or other buffer's that weren't visiting a file), fontified using the face `ido-virtual`. I need the first one of those files, but I can't find a way to retrieve it.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "closing" a file - in Emacs. Kill its buffer? Close its window?

Comment: @Drew Sorry, I meant killing its buffer.

Comment: I thought of a different approach and asked about that on [How to prompt for a virtual buffer (recently killed file) using Ido completion?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80713/how-to-prompt-for-a-virtual-buffer-recently-killed-file-using-ido-completion) There are answers to this questions on [How to reopen just killed buffer, like C-S-t in Firefox Browser?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/how-to-reopen-just-killed-buffer-like-c-s-t-in-firefox-browser), but they don't involve virtual buffers. Should I close this question?

Comment: Yes, please close/delete it, if it's not really what you're asking or it's a dup. Thx.

Comment: @Drew I'd rather close it than delete it, but as far as I can tell I cannot close it for good, I can only vote to close it (which I did). Can a moderator close it?

Comment: A moderator can delete it or close it. I've asked for that. Thx.

Answer (score -1):

You tagged your question with the `recentf` tag, but did you know what it meant? To quote the package documentation:

> This package maintains a list of recently opened files and makes it
> easy to visit them.  The recent files list is automatically saved
> across Emacs sessions.
>
> There are three ways to access recent files:
>
> (1) `M-x recentf-open` prompts for a recently opened file.
>
> (2) When this mode is enabled, a new “Open Recent” submenu is
> displayed in the “File” menu.
>
> (3) `M-x recentf-open-files` lists recently visited files in a
> buffer.
>
> You can customize the number of recent files displayed, the location
> of the menu and other options.  Type:
>
> ```
> M-x customize-group RET recentf RET
> ```
>
> To enable this package, add this line to your Init file:
>
> ```
> (recentf-mode 1)
> ```

You may wish to peruse [chapter 19.18 Convenience Features for Finding Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Conveniences.html) in the Emacs manual.

Comment: To answer the question you'd need to say how to use `recentf` to visit the *last-closed* file. How to tell which is the **last** one closed? It's not clear what OP even means by "close" a file, in Emacs: kill its buffer? close its window?

Comment: I tagged it `recentf` because Ido uses `recentf-list` to create its list of virtual buffers.